# How to tell search engines to use my updated robots.txt file?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Before, I had blocked the search engine robots to prevent crawling my website using the robots.txt file but now I want to unblock them.

I updated the robots.txt file and allowed the search engine robots to crawl my website but it seems the search engines still use my old robots.txt file, How I can tell the search engines to use my new robots.txt file? or is there something wrong in my robots.txt file?

The content of my old robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The content of my new robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

# Disallow these directories, url types & file-types
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /wp-
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /readme.html
Disallow: /license.txt
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.inc$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.gz$
Disallow: /*.wmv$
Disallow: /*.cgi$
Disallow: /*.xhtml$
Disallow: /*/wp-*
Disallow: /*/feed/*
Disallow: /*/*?s=*
Disallow: /*/*.js$
Disallow: /*/*.inc$

Allow: /wp-content/uploads/

User-agent: ia_archiver*
Disallow: /

User-agent: duggmirror
Disallow: /

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Error in your new robots.txt: empty lines aren’t allowed within a record (each record starts with a `User-agent` line). You can also remove `Allow: /` (as this is the default anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will need to be done independently for each search engine, otherwise it may just happen over time. For Google, use the Google Search Console tool. This will allow you to upload new robots.txt and submit for recrawling.

Comment: can you please show us how to submit our new robots.txt to Google Search Console?

Comment: Using the submit function of the robots.txt tester tool